# Two network cards in a single Windows 7 machine restrict traffic

Tags: networking

I have a computer with Windows 7 and two network cards:

NIC 1: 10.10.4.5/24
       Gateway set to 10.10.4.1

NIC 2: 192.168.3.9/24
       Gateway not set

When an application tries to make connection to a device (192.168.3.41) that is not connected (or ever has been) to the 192.168.3.0 network, a packet is sent to the gateway on the 10.10.4.0 network. This packet is refused by firewall rules and a TCP reset packet (RST, ACK) is sent back to the computer..

How can I sent up the computer to not send any packets bound for the 192.168.3.0 network to the gateway?

Comment: Since you state you are using a /24 mask on NIC2 Windows should resolve this on its own.  What does the output of 'route print' look like?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a new route to your route table. You can do this with the 'route' command funny enough:

```
route ADD 192.168.3.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 <New_Destination_IP>
```

Also if you want this to occur for only one interface you can add the interface specifier:

```
route ADD 192.168.3.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 <New_Destination_IT> if <Interface_Name>
```

Microsoft Reference Article about specifying static routes:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757323%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: This will not work for directly connected routes...